# Avoid mistaken "double-click" non-response when clicking a Windows taskbar tab and immediately clicking it again to send to background?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, gui, latency, double-click

When I click a taskbar tab to highlight that program's window, sometimes I only want a quick peek, and so I quickly click it again to send it to the background.

Unfortunately, Windows treats this as a double click and fails to respond for the second click. I don't want taskbar tabs to be affected by the double click delay, as I find it incredibly frustrating and inconsistent. I know it sounds tiny, but "mildly infuriating" things like this ruin a smooth experience.

How can I disable this 'feature' so that when I click a tab and then immediately click it again, Windows RESPONDS to my command and sends that window to the back?

Comment: Try just hovering over the Task Bar icon as that will show you the preview without upsetting anything.

Comment: I too do what @John suggests. Great way. Just hover the button and wait a second. There is a registry tweak and there are programs that can make this near instant if the delay is an issue. If you then hover the small thumbnail, it will hide all programs, show the desktop and put that window on it, so you only see that window. If you click on the thumbnail, you switch to the window, if you move away, it restores to what you had before.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also hate the way the thumbnail pops up and is it sometimes obscures what I need to click on. I wish I could disable that too. Besides, it wouldn't work in my case, since I don't want to wait for the thumbnail to pop up, I just want to quickly get on with whatever I'm doing.

Comment: That is built into Windows. It is very fast to use (1 or 2 seconds and gone). However to remove the thumbnail:  Type "gpedit.msc" without quotes and press ENTER.
Click "Administrative Templates" under "User Configuration"
Click "Start and taskbar"
Double click "Disable taskbar previews"
Click "Enable"
Click "Apply"
Restart computer

Comment: @John - Don't think gpedit.msc is included with the home edition of Windows 10. At least not in my version.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Home version does not include GPEDIT and is somewhat less configurable than PRO.